# if clause not working as it should

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a problem. I have wrote code that needs to point out the elements of array which are bigger that the next element of array.
You can see on the output picture that array $arr should contain only element 70 because `$ar[294]=70 > $ar[295]=69`. But code is somehow putting more elements to $arr which do not satisfly if statement `($ar[$i]>$ar[$i+1])`.

How is this possible?

```
$ar = array();
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($retcikonacno); $i++) {
    if ($retcikonacno[$i]["n2"] >= 1001 && $retcikonacno[$i]["n2"] <= 1013) {
        array_push($ar, $retcikonacno[$i]["vpont"]);
    }   
}

echo "ar=";
echo "</br>";
print_r($ar);

echo "</br>";
echo "-------------------";
echo "</br>";
echo "-------------------";

echo "</br>" . "</br>";

$arr = array();

$size = sizeof($ar)-1;
for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    if ($ar[$i] > $ar[$i+1]) {
        array_push($arr, $ar[$i]);
    }
}

echo "arr=";
echo "</br>";
print_r($arr);
```

---

OUTPUT:

[[image: Output]

Comment: Please post your code here so it is preserved for future SO visitors.

Comment: I did, please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Your question and your code do not match. According to your code you will have 13 items.

Comment: I am quite new to programming and this is bugging me whole day today. I have run this code again and it gives me the same output, which is 119 elements in the array $arr. It is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was consulting with my mentor and he solved this problem.

He said that it is possible that php (mistakenly and for unknown reason) read memory location of $ar[$i] and $ar[$i+1] and not the actual value of an array. So if clause was not valid.

SOLUTION:
Instead of creating array $ar as I did with array_push($ar, $retcikonacno[$i]["vpont"]), he used function intval,
so it was array_push($ar, intval($retcikonacno[$i]["vpont"])). This created array of correct values and if clase was doing good.